# It is possible to use the EWS Managed API from a Delphi Win32 VCL app (and how to start)?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, exchangewebservices

I'm currently investigating accessing Exchange Web Services (EWS) through SOAP (see e.g. [this prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084064/how-to-fix-unresolved-types-when-importing-exchange-web-services-ews-wsdl-file)), but there also is a recommended [EWS Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633709%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).

Would it be possible to use that API from a Win32 Delphi-XE2 app? I see people using the API from e.g. PHP with tools like [PHP-EWS](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/) so it looks possible from other languages than C#, but where would I start using Delphi?

Comment: The PHP-EWS page says about this tool that "It handles the NTLM authentication required to use the SOAP services (...)" so it looks like PHP-EWS is not using the managed API

Comment: The Managed API is nothing more than a friendly wrapper around the SOAP API, so in the end it still is SOAP - I would avoid that extra layer...

Comment: Delphi supports SOAP.  You start by using the WSDL import features in Delphi. Which you tried to do, and found that WSDL import features do not support ALL services equally well. So it appears that EWS is one of the ones that it doesn't support.