# Does this WSDL support Soap 1.1 AND Soap1.2?

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

Here is the [WSDL](https://api.krollcorp.com/EBusinessTest/Kroll.Dealer.EBusiness.svc/Docs?singleWsdl)

In the Binding section, it includes:

```
<wsdl:operation name="SubmitPurchaseOrder">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IEBusinessService/SubmitPurchaseOrder" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

It also includes:

```
<wsdl:operation name="SubmitPurchaseOrder">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IEBusinessService/SubmitPurchaseOrder" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

However, when I try to connect with `'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1` I get the error that it is expecting `type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER TO MY OWN QUESTION**

WSDL files can indicate support for both SOAP 1.1 and 1.2 in the same file. You can specify which binding you are using with:

`SoapClient::__setLocation()`

http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setlocation.php

**WsHttpBinding**

```
$client->__setLocation('https://api.krollcorp.com/EBusinessTest/Kroll.Dealer.EBusiness.svc/')
```

**BasicHttpBinding**

```
$client->__setLocation('https://api.krollcorp.com/EBusinessTest/Kroll.Dealer.EBusiness.svc/Basic')
```

Answer (score 3):

There 3 main difeferences between SOAP 1.2 and SOAP 1.1

1. SOAP 1.2 uses "application/soap+xml" as Content-Type and SOAP 1.1
   uses "text/xml".
2. SOAP 1.2 does not use SOAPAction header line.
3. SOAP 1.2 uses "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" as the envelope namespace and SOAP 1.1 uses
   "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/".

The good example which I got  from resource: http://www.herongyang.com/Web-Services/Perl-SOAP-1-2-Request-Differences-SOAP-1-1-and-1-2.html is below

```
SOAP 1.1 request: 

POST /WSShakespeare.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.xmlme.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://xmlme.com/WebServices/GetSpeech"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetSpeech xmlns="http://xmlme.com/WebServices">
      <Request>string</Request>
    </GetSpeech>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>


SOAP 1.2 request:

POST /WSShakespeare.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.xmlme.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetSpeech xmlns="http://xmlme.com/WebServices">
      <Request>string</Request>
    </GetSpeech>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Comment: I understand the differences in the Soap Request. I am asking if the WSDL file given indicates whether to use Soap 1.2 or Soap 1.1? It appears that it provides support for both, but I am not sure.

Comment: It looks like your question duplicates this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736845/can-a-wsdl-indicate-the-soap-version-1-1-or-1-2-of-the-web-service

WSDL supports both versions of soap and furtermore it can support both of them at the same wsdl