# Catch Soap response message c# .net

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Service Reference to communicate with WCF.
Now I can send the message with a method to the server. *
But I can't catch the response message. The request is fine, because I can handle the message with Fiddler Classic, but i need to handle it with c#.

Here is my code:

```
ServiceReference1.PUPHAXWSPortTypeClient client = new ServiceReference1.PUPHAXWSPortTypeClient();
        client.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
        client.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.UserName = "PUPHAX";
        client.ClientCredentials.HttpDigest.ClientCredential.Password = "puphax";
        await client.TABATCAsync("<ATC>N05BA%</ATC>"); //* this method
```

If i want to storage the data to a variable or ServiceReference1.TABATCResponse tABATCRequest i got an exception which is invalid UTF-8 bytes.

Sorry for my english, here is the service reference: http://neak.gov.hu//data/cms1030808/PUPHAXWS_v1.22.wsdl

Comment: You never assign the response to any variable. `var response= await client.TABATCAsync(whatever);`

Comment: `got an exception which is invalid UTF-8 bytes.` in that case neither the request nor the response are OK. Post the actual, full exception text. WCF uses the encoding specified in the response's Content-Type to read the contents. In fact, it's *extremely* unusual to pass raw strings with XML to a WCF method. The whole point of using WCF is to generate strongly typed clients, send objects and have WCF serialize them

Comment: The full exception message:

{"The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://xmlns.oracle.com/orawsv/PUPHAX/PUPHAXWS:RETURN. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type WindowsFormsApp3.ServiceReference1.OBJALAPType. '�bor kasvir�g vir�gos hajt�s pr�sleve' contains invalid UTF8 bytes.'.  Please see InnerException for more details."}

Comment: InnerException = {"There was an error deserializing the object of type WindowsFormsApp3.ServiceReference1.OBJALAPType. '�bor kasvir�g vir�gos hajt�s pr�sleve' contains invalid UTF8 bytes."}

Comment: Check first line of xml response and see if it contains UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Comment: The response doesn't show the encoding. It's only 

<?xml version="1.0" ?>

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i tried the var response = await client... thing, but it throw the UTF-8 exception

Comment: That's a *server* error. It doesn't matter if that's a government site, they're the worst when it comes to compliance. Most likely, they couldn't be bothered to use the correct `Content-Type` header and the response isn't Unicode. I'd bet it's a Hungarian codepage. The WSDL itself is... unfortunate because it's a SOAP v1.1 WSDL, which was replaced since 2007 by SOAP 1.2. WCF works with SOAP 1.2 at least. You'll have to create an ASMX proxy instead. Check [Can WSDL indicate version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736845/can-a-wsdl-indicate-the-soap-version-1-1-or-1-2-of-the-web-service)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Can u help me a bit about how can i create ASMX proxy?